# Proving DeMorgan's Rules $\overline{A\cup B} = \overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help in checking if my proofs have any logical faults or disconnects.
I am trying to prove that $\overline{A\cup B} = \overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$

I am using the 2 part approach where we show $l.h.s \subset r.h.s$ and $r.h.s \subset l.h.s$

Part 1

Consider $x \in \overline{A\cup B}$.
This implies $x \notin A\cup B$.
Which means $x \notin A$ as well as $x \notin B$.
Above statement can be rephrased as $x \in \overline{A}$ as well as $x \in \overline{B}$ and written as $x \in \overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$.
This proves that $\overline{A\cup B} \subset \overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$.

Part 2

Consider $x \in \overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$.
This implies $x \notin A$ as well as $x \notin B$.
It means $x \notin A\cup B$.
And it follows that $x \in \overline{A\cup B}$
Hence $\overline{A\cup B} \subset \overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$.

However, I feel that Part2 is just an upside down version of Part1, and hence have a feeling that one of (or either) parts above is not sound.

For Part 1, I have an alternate proof though as below:
Part 1a

we start with the fact that $A \subset A\cup B$.
By applying the law of complements reversing the inclusion order, $\overline{A\cup B} \subset \overline{A}$.
Similarly we can show that $\overline{A\cup B} \subset \overline{B}$
The above two statements can be true only if $\overline{A\cup B} \subset \overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$.

Would really appreciate it if someone can kind of disillusion me here a bit.
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that $\lnot(A \cup B) = \lnot A \cap \lnot B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254808/proving-that-lnota-cup-b-lnot-a-cap-lnot-b)

Comment: A truth table would be more succinct.

Comment: hi @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you. i looked at [Proving that ¬(A∪B)=¬A∩¬B](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254808/proving-that-lnota-cup-b-lnot-a-cap-lnot-b) and feel yes, looks like though Part1 and Part2 look upside down versions of each other, both are sound. Would you also agree?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, i do a bit of programming, and that way is quite obvious because you transform the logical operators AND, OR with the complements of the variables quite often. And ofcourse, obvious is better, must agree :-)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. You can combine the 2 parts by saying that for every $x $ we have $ x\in \overline {A\cup B}\iff$ $\iff x\not \in (A\cup B) \iff$ $ (\neg(x\in A\lor x\in B))\iff$ $ (x\not \in A\land x\not \in B)\iff$ $ (x\in \bar A\land x\in \bar B)\iff$ $\iff x\in \bar A\cap \bar B.$